# How to remove space between SearchIcon and Text in SearchView in android?

Tags: android, searchview

I am using the SearchView and It is display Like, [image]

And I want to Like This, [image]

I am not using Action bar. So how to Remove Space between SearchIcon and Text in SearchView? How it is Possible? Please Guide me.

```
And My XML file is, 

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/svSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp" >
    </SearchView>

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lstSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/svSearch" >
    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Apply padding right to EditText.

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <SearchView
        android:id="@+id/svSearch"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/five_dp" >
    </SearchView></RelativeLayout>   I am using SearchView not EditText.

Comment: So have you applied padding right?

Comment: are you using actionbar searchview?

Comment: @PiyushGupta Yes I am applied PaddingRight but can not any change.

Comment: @Pragna But when you change your text search view icon will be disapper

Comment: @MoradiyaAkash No, I am Using only SearchView But not use in Actionbar.

Comment: you use SearchView of android V7 support library?

Comment: @PiyushGupta No Not any Change same as Like Before. See ScreenShot 1 in My Question Please.

Comment: @MoradiyaAkash No, I am Using Widgets.

Comment: @Pragna Yeah i have seen it. But i tested when you change your text in search view its starts from starting after icon disappear and its fine

Comment: @PiyushGupta Are you using Widget or android V7 Support Library? Because I am using Widget.

Comment: I have copied your code in my file and just run the code.

Comment: @PiyushGupta I send you my Updated Code With PaddingRight Please check it. <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"; xmlns:tools="schemas.android.com/tools"; android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" > <SearchView android:id="@+id/svSearch" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" android:layout_marginTop="5dip" android:paddingRight="20dp" > </SearchView> 
</RelativeLayout>

Comment: OK. Me checking and is this ur demo projcet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64527/discussion-between-piyush-gupta-and-pragna).

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I solved it modifying the padding for rendered textview within search view programmatically

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Reduce space between search icon and text
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) findViewById(R.id.action_search);
    TextView textView = (TextView) searchView.findViewById(R.id.search_src_text);
    textView.setPadding(2, 0, 0, 0);
    return true;
}
```